# How do I prevent my android app from losing user data when it is inactive for a long time?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am helping with an android app that involves keeping track of how much a person travels, and adding points for that person depending on the distance travelled. This means having to keep Data or internet access on the whole time.

The problem I am having with the app is that when the phone device is sleeping or the app is inactive for a long time, it will lose all the user information (username, e-mail, and point information). Even if I make the device use the method to track the person travelling, it will still lose the information after some time. Thus, it won't allow me to save the distance travelled data to the user.

I kept track of what causes this, and found that over time, the memory for the app would stop running, causing the user information to turn into null. I have tried finding solutions online, but the android developer website doesn't give any clear solutions. The closest I could find is this page about direct boot mode: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/direct-boot

I read over the page, but for some reason the application gets an error saying it can't run the code:
Context deviceProtected = appContext.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext();
The whole page just doesn't do a good job explaining how I'm supposed to use this code, or where I'm supposed to run certain code.

Does anybody know a better solution to my problem, or know how to properly use the Context class and Direct Boot to prevent app memory from being lost?

TL;DR How do I prevent my app from losing user/profile data, and keep certain methods/services running when the app is inactive for a long time?

Comment: "How do I prevent my app from losing user/profile data" -- save the data to a database, `SharedPreferences`, or some other form of file. "and keep certain methods/services running when the app is inactive for a long time" -- you don't. Your process cannot run forever. You can use a foreground service to maximize the run time, but you should still be saving your data to disk periodically.

Comment: I actually tried using SharedPreferences to save data. However, I was having issues with using that too. For some reason, after I have my program save the key-value pairs in the editor, the file for the SharedPreferences is not created. I read that there is supposed to be an XML file in the data file for the app, but I am not seeing it. Is there some step I'm missing?

Comment: "but I am not seeing it" -- we do not know where you are looking for it. `SharedPreferences` files are stored in your app's portion of what the Android SDK refers to as [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), and the only way you usually see that is via the IDE or `adb` commands.

Comment: I am checking it vis Device File Explorer on Android Studio. I checked data/data/"My App" folder. It says "run-as: Could not set capabilities", and not files inside. I decided to try checking internal data through my computer as well. I checked Phone/Android/Data/"My App" folder, but I still don't see the preference file that my data should be stored in.

Comment: "It says "run-as: Could not set capabilities", and not files inside" -- perhaps you are running a `release` build and not a `debug` one. "I decided to try checking internal data through my computer as well" -- that is not possible, except via Android Studio, `adb`, or similar tools. "I checked Phone/Android/Data/"My App" folder, but I still don't see the preference file that my data should be stored in" -- that is what the Android SDK refers to as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). Preferences are not stored there.

Comment: I tried running in debug mode. I am still not seeing the sharedpreference file when I check the app data folder through Device File Explorer. Though while this is a problem, do you know what code I should use to access the sharedpreference folder and get variables? I am reading that I need a Context abstract class, but I'm not sure how to declare it properly without getting errors. The main error I am getting is that I can't declare an abstract method in a non-abstract class. I want to get saved user information from sharedpreferences in a profile class that isn't abstract.

Comment: "I am reading that I need a Context abstract class, but I'm not sure how to declare it properly without getting errors" -- your `Activity` is a `Context`. You do not create your own `Context`. "I am still not seeing the sharedpreference file when I check the app data folder through Device File Explorer" -- then perhaps ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you provide a [mcve] showing how you are trying to work with the `SharedPreferences`.